# Conditioning on dependent variables

Tags: conditional-probability, markov-process

Given that $Y$ is exclusively dependent on $X$ and that $Z$ is exclusively dependent on $Y$, I would like to state that

$p(z|x,y)=p(z|y)$.

This makes intuitive sense because knowing $x$ in addition to $y$ does not seem to add any further constraints to the conditioned sample space

Is this correct? If so, what is the proper way to show it is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean that $Z$ given $Y$ is **conditionally independent** of everything. So your equality follows from definitions.

Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence. There are two ways to look at conditional independence. One:
$$
p(z,x|y) = p(z|y)p(x|y),
$$
or two:
$$
p(z|y,x) = p(z|y).
$$

Comment: Can I say that $Z|Y$ is conditionally independent of everything even when I know that $Y$ depends on $X$? All I know is that if you tell me $Y$ I can fully describe the random variable $Z$ without any additional knowledge. Is that equivalent to conditional independence?

Comment: @DanielV "if you tell me $Y$ I can fully describe the random variable $Z$" ... that is equivalent to "$Z$ is independent of $X$ given $Y$."